# TYPO3 Multilanguage do not show new content elements only the references

Tags: typo3, frontend, content-type, multilingual

I'm using a TYPO3-Installation 4.5.14.
I need another language, but I'm not the Developer. At the moment there is german as default and english. I also need "spanish". So I add a new Website-Language "spanish" and add a new translation for my page (id=9).

If I copy the standard element from default, the content element is a reference and I'll see it in frontend, too.

But If I add a **new** content module (text or headline), I won't see it in frontend!

If I try it in "english" - it works, but not for my new language "spanish".

Here's my TypoScript

```
# languages
##################
config.linkVars = L
config.uniqueLinkVars = 1

config.sys_language_mode = content_fallback
config.sys_language_overlay = 1

#config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated

# german :
config.sys_language_uid = 0
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE.UTF8

# english :
[globalVar = GP:L = 1]
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_EN.UTF8
config.htmlTag_langKey = en
[global]

# spanish :
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config.sys_language_uid = 2
config.language = es
config.locale_all = es_ES.UTF8
config.htmlTag_langKey = es
[global]
```

I have no idea ... where's the problem ?!
The ID for Spanish is ID2 see Screenshot

It's a LIVE-Website, so I can't show you my tests ..
http://www.health-spa-award.com/index.php?id=9&L=0...1...2

And a screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the uid of your new language "Spanish" is 2? Please check this first.

Comment: Hi, yes the ID = 2 for Spanish and ID = 1 for english.